# How to recover from CUDA errors when using cudaLaunchHostFunc instead of cudaStreamAddCallback

Tags: cuda

The [documentation page for `cudaStreamAddCallback`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1g74aa9f4b1c2f12d994bf13876a5a2498) says that it is "slated for eventual deprecation and removal" and to use cudaLaunchHostFunc instead. However, [documentation for `cudaLaunchHostFunc`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g05841eaa5f90f27124241baafb3e856f) says that the host functions is not allowed to make any CUDA calls. The callback for `cudaLaunchHostFunc` also is of type

```cpp
typedef void (CUDART_CB *cudaHostFn_t)(void *userData);
```

instead of

```cpp
typedef void (CUDART_CB *cudaStreamCallback_t)(cudaStream_t stream, cudaError_t status, void *userData);
```

that `cudaStreamAddCallBack` accepts. I can include the stream information in `void* userData` but how am I supposed to recover if an error occurs after the callback is attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told by CUDA folks that even though `cudaAddStreamCallback` is marked as deprecated there is currently no alternative to it and that `cudaAddStreamCallback` is not going to be removed until some alternative arrives.

Comment: Was this said "on the record"? If so, can you say who said this and perhaps link to where it was said?